# Are questions about "philosophy" of mathematics education on-topic?

Tags: discussion

> [The Philosophy of mathematics education](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_mathematics_education) is an interdisciplinary area of study and research based on the intersection of the fields of mathematics education and the philosophy of mathematics, the latter being understood in an inclusive sense to include multidisciplinary theorizing about mathematics incorporating philosophical, sociological, anthropological, semiotic, historical, ethnomathematical, etc., perspectives.
>
> "*Quoted from Wikipedia*"

**Question.** Are questions about "philosophy" of mathematics education on-topic here in MESE?

Comment: I agree with quid's answer (Yes - *obviously*) but note that the wikipage linked to provides "further details" in a paper by Paul Ernest; it also mentions a journal published/edited by Ernest. This journal (*Philosophy of Mathematics Education Journal*) is unrefereed, and I have not heard positive comments about it; I would be happy to learn if others have heard otherwise.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman, but according to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_Mathematics_Education_Journal), the journal is "peer-reviewed."  But I do agree with you that the journal does not seem to be a serious one.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche In the most recent issue, http://people.exeter.ac.uk/PErnest/pome27/index.html, "For details of the Aims of the Journal and Editorial policy see earlier issues up to no. 19." From #19 (http://people.exeter.ac.uk/PErnest/pome19/index.htm) and earlier: **Editorial policy.** *In keeping with the aims of the journal the editorial hand is used very lightly. This is an international unrefereed journal which aims to stimulate the sharing of ideas for no other reason than an interest in the ideas and love of discussion among its contributors and readers.* (Interpret as you see fit...)

Comment: The Wikipedia entry for the journal is in error, then.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman The description at the [website](https://socialsciences.exeter.ac.uk/education/research/centres/stem/publications/pmej/pome35/index.html) has now changed slightly: "Editorial policy. The editorial hand is used very lightly.  This is an international refereed journal which aims to stimulate the sharing of ideas for no reason other than an interest in these ideas and love of discussion among its contributors and readers."

Answer (score 6):

Yes. *Obviously* -- it is hoped -- with the restriction that they fulfil the standards generally applicable to questions on this site and on the SE network; especially regarding 'opinion based' and 'too broad.'