# Are questions about teaching "philosophy of math" on-topic?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, questions

Obviously questions about *teaching philosophy of math* are quite different from questions about *philosophy of teaching math* which we discussed about them in a [meta post](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238/are-questions-about-philosophy-of-mathematics-education-on-topic) before.

There are essential connections between philosophy of math as a field of philosophy and logic as a field of mathematics. Also the philosophy of math courses are a part of course tables in many math departments. The philosophical approach of a logic teacher could be very important in his teaching. Consequently any question about useful techniques for a better teaching in philosophy of math could improve the quality of teaching logic in a department.

> **Question.** Are questions about teaching "philosophy of math" on-topic in MESE?

Comment: I do not exactly know it, my first gut feeling is "no". Philosophy is not mathematics. But of course there might be borderline questions...

Comment: We actually have a user whose profile say he does research in the philosoohy of math at a philosoohy of science institute. If we can find out who he is, we can ask them their opinion.

Comment: Philosophy of math is often treated as a part of mathematics in the United States.  For example, it has an AMS classification number, and there are sometimes AMS special sessions on the philosophy of math at regional and national meetings.

Comment: I would answer "yes".  As said, philosophy of math is closely connected to math itself (particularly logic), and e.g. at my faculty there is a course in "philosophy and history of mathematics".  In fact, I'd even count "history of mathematics" in.